# Unused space in top bar

Tags: feature-request, design, search, top-bar

In the current top bar design there is an unused space between search box and user icon:

> [image: topbar space]

I suggest to expand search box to obtain unused space (at least when focus on search, like it already done on [Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)).

Comment: This space is meant to support smaller screens, it is not really "unused". (Try to resize the screen, see how that space becomes smaller and smaller.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard width could be adjustable according to the page size.

Comment: @ShadowWizard one step to reduce width on my iPad changes [topbar style radically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMaJE.jpg).

Comment: You mean make the search box width dynamic, to fill the space?

Comment: @ShadowWizard yep. To fill the space.

Comment: I made a Stylish user style for that! https://userstyles.org/styles/161821/stack-exchange-full-width-search-bar

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime, you can use a Stylish sheet (https://userstyles.org/styles/161821/stack-exchange-full-width-search-bar)

CSS:

```
.top-bar .searchbar { max-width: initial !important; }
```